# Vector graphics formats documentation

Tags: vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I would like to extract vectors from a vector graphics file to use in my own programs. For example, vectors from a .ai file. What would be a good way to do it? I have seen free converters, so I'm assuming that there must exist an openly accessible .ai documentation. Converting to another format that's open would be ok for me, too.

Comment: A good question. I'd wish to know the answer too. There is the documentation for Adobe Postscript language in the wild somewhere. But it's not enough for parsing modern AI and EPS files anyway.